# Check prime number

Tags: python

```
def isPrime(n):
    if n>1:
        for i in range(2,n):
            if (n % i==0):
                return False
            else:
                return True
    else:
        return False
```

This code worked in most cases, but when input n=133, it returned True as output. Please show me the error.

Comment: Check n=9. See if you can figure this out without our help. You'll learn more for sure.

Comment: Check any number other than 2...

Comment: a small optimization would be using `range(2,n,2)`, all even numbers except 2 are not prime ;)

Comment: your isPrime function is incorrect, you cannot return True in this manner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that your code could return True in the first iteration of the loop, you need to check for the other values.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see how your loop works.
For value such as 3 your loop will have n%i check i.e. `3%2 which won't satisfy the condition`. So it will return `true`.
But `for value such as 9`. Loop will check `9%2=0` which again doesn't satisfy the condition and `returns True`.
So use something like.

```
def isPrime(n):
    if n>1:
        for i in range(2,n):
            if (n % i==0):
                return False
            else:
                x=False
        return x;
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

So I ran this and it seems this function will return True for any odd number because it returns false on the first iteration, which is checking if it's divisible by 2. Overall, your function is pretty much wrong, here is how I would approach it.

```
def isPrime(n):
    div = True 
    for i in range(2,int(n**0.5)):
        if n%i==0:
            div = False
            break
    return div
```

Here what I did was I only checked prime factors upto the square root of the number (because if a number has a prime factor greater than its square root(but not the number itself), it must also have a prime factor less than its square root, so we do not need to check further), and I exited from the loop whenever even once it was divisible by something. I checked and it's working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your loop is that when you are iterating through the for loop, it always returning either True or False. To prevent that, what you should create a counter which changes its value accordingly.

```
def PrimeChecker(n):
    if n < 1:
        return f'{n} is less than 1. So, not prime'  # You can add this if you 
        # want.

    else:
        for i in range(2, n):  # The main loop
            counter = True  # The counter
            if n % i == 0:  # If it becomes divisible....
                counter = False # Counter becomes false.
                break  # Break out of loop

        return counter  # Return False or True
```

Hope that helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Most efficient Primechecker program :)

```
from math import sqrt
def checkprime(x):
    if x > 2 and x % 2 == 0:
        return False
    elif x < 2:
        return False

    else:
        for i in range(2, int(sqrt(x)) + 1):
            if x % i == 0:
                return False
        return True
    return False
```